# Submitting to action but showing a different page HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can i submit the data to the save.php but show another page instead, every time i click it goes to the save.php rather than the display.php

```
form name="theform" action="save.php" id="addENT" method="POST">
    <div align  id="Title-Name"><b>Input:</b></div>
    <div id="login-box-field"><textarea class="Title-Input" type="text" name="Title-Input"></textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit redirects the page to `save.php`. All you need to do is to redirect to `display.php` back in `save.php` after you're done with the processing.

See [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) for more details.

#### Basically

```
header("Location: display.php");
exit; //Stop executing further.
```